# How to determine maximum speed of cpu in linux (MIPS architecture)

Tags: linux, mips, cpu-speed

i want to determine maximum speed of cpu in MHz with linux operating system and MIPS hardware. With command `cat /proc/cpuinfo` it results in `BogoMIPS=1000.00`. And

```
`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq`
```

is not working. How can i convert it into MHz.Or what unit is used for BogoMIPS??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
```

or this:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
```

There should be similar files for the minimum frequency as well.

Answer (score 0):

The information should be under cpuinfo. What does it give you if you enter:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Hz
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't give what the user is asking, as the speed listed under `/proc/cpuinfo` is the current speed, and may differ from the max speed if frequency scaling is in effect.